# Given 2 tables, how to consolidate them into a view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Given the following ***ADuser*** table:

```
AD Group    UserID
Group1      User1
Group2      User2
Group3      User1
Group3      User3
```

and ***Group_Access*** table:

```
AD Group    Org Codes
Group1   M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|
Group2   123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|
Group3   12345|
```

how do i consolidate them into a view so that we end up with something like this, where the orgcodes are combined under 1 matching userid?

```
UserID      Org Codes
User1       M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|12345|
User2       123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|
User3       12345|
```

Notice that because User1 belong to mutiple groups, i.e. Group1 and Group3, all org codes in those 2 groups for user1 are consolidated into1 in the final view, appending the additional `12345|` org code

What Ive tried so far:

```
CREATE VIEW UserOrgCodesView
AS SELECT ADuser.UserID, Group_Access.[Org Codes]
FROM ADuser
INNER JOIN Group_Access ON ADuser.[AD Group]=Group_Access.[AD Group];
```

but this has yielded in the following

```
UserID  Org Codes
User1   M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|12345|
User2   123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|
User1   12345|
User3   12345|
```

Comment: @DaleK Ive updated the post

Comment: The join didn't work because the `AD Group` columns have different formats - `Group1` and `AD_Group1` can't be joined without manipulation.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh my, youre right. bad mistake on my part haha. now im getting something back, however, i dont know how to consolidate the same user into one org codes row. please check updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STRING_AGG` (if SQL Server 2017 onwards) or `XML PATH` (if before SQL Server 2017).

```sql
CREATE TABLE aduser (ADGroup SYSNAME, UserID sysName)

create table group_access (ADgroup sysname, OrgCodes VARCHAR(4000))

insert into aduser values
('Group1','User1'),
('Group2','User1');

insert into group_access values
('Group1','M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|'),
('Group2',' 123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|')

CREATE VIEW UserOrgCodesView_SQL2017onwards
AS
SELECT ad.UserID, STRING_AGG(gc.OrgCodes,'') as Orgcodes 
FROM aduser as ad
inner join group_access as gc
on gc.ADGroup = ad.ADGroup
group by ad.UserID

CREATE VIEW UsersOrgCodesView_Before2017
as
SELECT oad.UserID, STUFF((SELECT gc.OrgCodes+'' FROM group_access as gc
inner join aduser as ad
on gc.ADGroup = ad.ADGroup 
where ad.UserID = oad.UserID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') as Orgcodes 
FROM aduser as oad
group by Oad.UserID
```

Comment: btw what if i dont have a trailing delimiter, for example `123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P` notice no | at the end. does that impact the solution?

Comment: @Cataster, For SQL 2017 onwards not a problem. For earlier versions, I have updated my answer

Comment: does this work for both scenarios, if i have and if i dont have a trailing | delimiter?

Comment: Great. one more question if you dont mind. What if we have another requirement to create another view that has the same results but includes the ADGroup as well, consolidated? for example, User1 belongs to Groups1 and 3 right? So then there would be 3 columns,`ADGroup, UserID,Org Codes` Values 1st row: `Group1|Group3 User1 M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|12345| `

Comment: @Cataster, yes. you can use the same logic for concatenating `groups`, as we have concatenated `orgcodes`

Comment: can you check if this is right? its difficult because the ADGroups dont have a delimiter like the Org Codes so how to add | `CREATE VIEW ADGroupUsersOrgCodesView_Before2017
as
SELECT STUFF((SELECT gc.ADgroup+'' FROM group_access as gc
inner join aduser as ad
on gc.ADGroup = ad.ADGroup 
where ad.UserID = oad.UserID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') as [AD Group], 
oad.UserID, 
STUFF((SELECT gc.OrgCodes+'' FROM group_access as gc
inner join aduser as ad
on gc.ADGroup = ad.ADGroup 
where ad.UserID = oad.UserID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') as Orgcodes 
FROM aduser as oad
group by Oad.UserID`

Comment: @Cataster, use delimiter as `|`. `SELECT gc.ADgroup+'|'` for concatenating `|` to the ADGroup.

Comment: I got it working now: `CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ADGroupsUsersOrgCodesView1_Before2017]
AS
SELECT STUFF((SELECT gc.[AD Group]+'|' FROM Group_Access as gc
INNER JOIN ADUser as ad
ON gc.[AD Group] = ad.[AD Group] 
WHERE ad.UserID = oad.UserID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') as [AD Group], 
oad.UserID, 
STUFF((SELECT gc.[Org Codes]+'' FROM Group_Access as gc
INNER JOIN ADUser as ad
ON gc.[AD Group] = ad.[AD Group] 
WHERE ad.UserID = oad.UserID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') as [Org Codes]
FROM ADUser as oad
GROUP BY Oad.UserID
GO` but i feel like its redundant. how do i simplify it?

Comment: @Cataster, I would suggest you to post a separate question. answering over comments, will lead to confusion

Comment: You're right, i feel like it would be downvoted though because they would complain that this is a duplicate of this question already, even though its not, but the SO community can downvote sometimes for simple reasons like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217581/discussion-between-cataster-and-venkataraman-r).

Answer (score 3):

> where the orgcodes are combined under 1 matching userid?

[You'll need to use `STRING_AGG` which is only available in SQL Server 2017 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This query also uses `TRIM()` on the input `[Org Codes]` value to help prevent `'||'` appearing in the output when existing strings are concatenated together.

```
SELECT
    u.UserId,
    STRING_AGG( TRIM( '|' FROM g.[Org Codes] ), '|' ) AS [Org Codes]
FROM
    ADuser AS u
    INNER JOIN Group_Access AS g ON u.[AD Group] = g.[AD Group]
GROUP BY
    u.UserId;
```

That said, it's generally a bad idea to denormalize data like this. You should return row-oriented data to clients and only denormalize data in your UI layer.

Comment: Im getting an error when i add AS for the view: `CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UserOrgCodesView] AS SELECT u.Us....`. its saying CREATE VIEW MUST be the only statement in the batch...I suspected its because I had 'Go'. I removed that and still complaining

Comment: Also regarding denormalizing the data, youre right, we did discuss it but unfortunately thats the only way we could implement this. We thought of numerous solutions but they had limitations and this was the only way execution and implementation wise to proceed with. For example, we tried having a table that has multiple Access columns, but that limits the hierarchy for the security we are building. we also tried using a DAX formula in excel but it limited search to 1 user for org codes.

Answer (score 1):

you may try below:

```
CREATE TABLE TmpTblADUser (GroupName VARCHAR(10), UserID VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TmpTblGroupAccess VALUES
  ('Group1', 'M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|'),
  ('Group2', '123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|'),
  ('Group3', '12345|')



CREATE TABLE TmpTblGroupAccess (GroupName VARCHAR(10), OrgCodes VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO TmpTblGroupAccess VALUES
('Group1', 'M500_ABC|1098|123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|234G|'),
('Group2', '123_KL|Z45557|f908L_P|'),
('Group3', '12345|')

CREATE VIEW UserOrgCodesView
AS SELECT u.UserID, g.OrgCodes
FROM TmpTblADUser u
INNER JOIN TmpTblGroupAccess g ON u.GroupName = g.GroupName;


SELECT t.UserID,
       STUFF((SELECT OrgCodes + '' FROM UserOrgCodesView WHERE UserID = t.UserID FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '') AS GrupList  
       FROM UserOrgCodesView t
GROUP BY t.UserID
```

Comment: This is a nice answer too! i see that you just join on the view but the consolidation happenes adhoc by running the SELECT statement standalone. how do you combine that SELECT statement at the end with the CREATE VIEW? can you post a 2nd edit without delting the first solution?

Comment: I've used the view definition in your question. I removed the LEFT function that was unnecessary.